# Make Error: Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:

Tags: c, gcc, makefile, x86-64

I've just started programming in C and decided to use make to build my sample app. Compiling the files using the GCC command works fine, however, using make fails with an error. If **make** just executes the gcc command under the hood, I don't see why this is even possible.

**Here are the list of files:**

makefile.make:

```
app.o: app.c helper.h
    gcc -c app.c

helper.o: helper.h helper.c
    gcc -c helper.c

app: app.o helper.o
    gcc app.o helper.o -o app
```

app.c

```
/*
 * file: app.c
 */
#include "helper.h"

int main() {
    do_something();
    return 0;
}
```

helper.h

```
/*
 * helper.h
 */
void do_something();
```

helper.c

```
/*
 * file: helper.c
 */
#include <stdio.h>
#include "helper.h"

void do_something() {
    printf("Test\n");
    printf("Testsss\n");
}
```

**The Problem: Running "make app" throws the error message**

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_do_something", referenced from:
      _main in app.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [app] Error 1
```

**Things Ive tried that works:**

- Compiling and Linking manually using gcc (using the commands from
  make executed serially)
- Using "make app.o" and "make helper.o" then running "gcc app.o helper.o -o app" compiles and links the app correctly

Comment: have you tried `make -stdlib=libstdc++ -lstdc++` ?

Comment: You using gcc or clang?  From your error it looks like you are at least linking with clang.  What do you get if you include the -v flag during linking?

Comment: this is just "C" compiled with "GCC". am i right to assume that make does not do anything special, it just executes the command to build things up. "app.o" and "helper.o" works, but not "app". im pretty sure "app" is just a simple linking using gcc: "gcc app.o helper.o -o app". the frustrating thing is that "gcc app.o helper.o -o app" works just fine.

Comment: ok i feel stupid about asking this question. how do i close this? (answer by @Ayseeyou is correct)

Comment: to have make use a make file that has a non-standard name, enter: 'make -f filename target'

Comment: @HackofAllCodes: One of the close-vote reasons is "unlikely to help future readers, because it was a simple typo or something".  IDK about closing your own questions, but 5 close votes can close it.  re: your problem:  Write your Makefile with the first target being a default or everything target, so you can just type `make` instead of `make app`.

Comment: Do you want to close this question or just delete it? I think you can delete it yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rename "makefile.make" to "makefile" or "Makefile". "app.o" and "helper.o" seems to work but i think thats just make doing its default instructions.

Comment: somehow, sublime text magically appended ".make" to my makefile - renamed and it now works well

Comment: Could also supply `-f makefile.make` to `make`